# How to retrieve entity from key value in GQL

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, gql

I am using Google App Engine's datastore and wants to retrieve an entity whose key value is written as

```
ID/Name

id=1
```

Can anyone suggest me a GQL query to view that entity in datastore admin console and also in my python program?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From your application use the [get_by_id()](http://code.google.com/intl/it/appengine/docs/python/datastore/modelclass.html#Model_get_by_id) class method of the Model:

```
entity = YourModel.get_by_id(1)
```

From Datastore viewer you should use the `KEY` function:

```
SELECT * FROM YourModel WHERE __key__ = KEY('YourModel',1)
```

Answer (score 0):

An application can retrieve a model instance for a given Key using the [get()](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/functions.html#get) function.

```
class member(db.Model):
    firstName=db.StringProperty(verbose_name='First Name',required=False)
    lastName=db.StringProperty(verbose_name='Last Name',required=False)

...

id = int(self.request.get('id'))
entity= member.get(db.Key.from_path('member', id))
```

I'm not sure how to return a specific entity in the admin console.

Comment: thanx buddy it worked but still I cannot use this in datastore admin console. do you have any idea for that?